# Sending terminal commands via SSH connection: Nested pipes

Tags: ssh, unix, shell, putty

Hoi everybody,

I am currently having a problem with sending commands over SSH via command line to a server. To have an easy example, I always send the "pwd" command - which should return the current folder you are in.

I build the initial SSH connection successfully with the following command:

```
sshg3 user@server#port 'pwd'
```

which connects to the server and short the home folder.

Afterwards, I use sudo su - user2 - because the user has more rights as user (needed for specific tasks):

```
sshg3 user@server#port "echo pwd|sudo su - user2"
```

Here, however, if I want to concat multiple commands after one another, I need to insert "" - otherwise it does not work:

```
sshg3 user@server#port "echo ""pwd;pwd""|sudo su - user2"
```

If I have no or only one ", the result is:

```
pwd
-bash: line 1: {homefolder}: is a directory
```

Now, afterwards using lftp I need to upload data to that server using yet another user. Using another pipe, I get that to work with a single command the following way:

```
sshg3 user@server#port "echo ""echo pwd|lftp -u user3 -p 1234 server2""|sudo su - user2"
```

And now comes the problem: Sending multiple commands to the second server does not work. If I use the same pattern I used before (""), I get this result:

```
sshg3 user@server#port "echo ""echo ""pwd;pwd""|lftp -u user3 -p 1234 server2""|sudo su - user2"
```

This prints:

```
echo pwd
bash: pwd|lftp -u user3 -p 1234 server2: command not found
```

The most part I got by using the answer in [this][1] thread - but now I am stuck.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is your local shell? I think `"echo ""pwd;pwd""|sudo su - user2"` is equivalent to `"echo pwd;pwd|sudo su - user2"` because of how the shell parses it. Did you mean `\"`?

Comment: Additionally I cannot tell what exactly you are trying to do. Maybe if I knew what "this thread" is... Please [edit] the question and at least fix the link.

Comment: Still I'm not sure what the command should do and I have no experience with `lftp`. But I know these `echo`-s are awful. Do you need `su` to provide you an interactive shell after `lftp` finishes? Something like this seems to be a way better syntax: `sshg3 user@server#port 'sudo -u user2 -- lftp -u user3 -p 1234 -c "pwd; pwd" server2'`. Untested though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do on the remote server. It looks like you want to execute commands which depend on the response of other commands (like `pwd`, which prints the working directory). Possibly you also want to use a password ("echo pwd") for `su`, I am not sure which.

I would suggest one of the following approaches:

- Write a script on the remote server that does what you want. Execute that script via `ssh`. Give the script additional information, like passwords, as arguments when you call it.
- If you can't store the script on the remote server permanently: Write the script anyway, and then pipe and execute the whole script through `ssh`.
- Use `expect` to script a complicated interactive session via `ssh`, where you call various programs, which in turn expect user input.

In any case, I don't think you'll get far messing around with `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you could tell us what you're trying to achieve rather than *how* you're trying to achieve it, then we could probably help out...

---

In the meantime, as I can't help with your original problem, let's address the following:

```
sshg3 user@server#port "echo ""echo ""pwd;pwd""|lftp -u user3 -p 1234 server2""|sudo su - user2"
```

Bash will break this into arguments based on unquoted whitespace, thus the arguments are:

1. `sshg3`
2. `user@server#port`
3. `"echo ""echo ""pwd;pwd""|lftp -u user3 -p 1234 server2""|sudo su - user2"`

After removal of the quoting from argument 3, it will look like this: (I don't think that's what you intended)

```
echo echo pwd;pwd|ltfp -u user3 -p 1234 server2|sudo su - user2
```

You can confirm this with the following snippet.

Put your command into the array with `X=( YOUR_COMMAND )`:

```
$ X=(sshg3 user@server#port "echo ""echo ""pwd;pwd""|lftp -u user3 -p 1234 server2""|sudo su - user2")
$ for i in "${X[@]}"; do echo "${i}"; done
sshg3
user@server#port
echo echo pwd;pwd|lftp -u user3 -p 1234 server2|sudo su - user2
```

---

The cleaned version of argument 3 will be passed to the remote system and will (probably) be interpreted like so:

- Command 1 arguments:

  1. `echo`
  2. `echo`
  3. `pwd`
- Command 2 arguments: (`stdout` wired to Command 3's `stdin` because of pipe / `|`)

  1. `pwd`
- Command 3 arguments: (`stdout` wired to Command 4's `stdin`)

  1. `lftp`
  2. `-u`
  3. `user3`
  4. `-p`
  5. `1234`
  6. `server2`
- Command 4 arguments:

  1. `sudo`
  2. `su`
  3. `-u`
  4. `user2`

Again, you can confirm this by logging in and running the cleaned third line from the remote shell.

---

There are a few things to note about this:

- You probably didn't mean to echo `echo pwd` to stdout (which is what Command 1 will do)
- `lftp` won't expect an absolute path (and nothing else) to be given on `stdin`
- `su` very likely won't expect whatever the output of `lftp` is to be given on `stdin`... `su` will invoke `user2`'s shell.